# Map partitioned table with partition discriminator column

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a legacy Oracle 10g database. This database has a table `ITEMDELIVERY` with a column `DELIVERY_DATE`. The table is partitioned by this column. Because of that, the primary key of this table is a compound one involving the columns `ITEMDELIVERY_ID` and `DELIVERY_DATE`.
There is another table `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` having a FK to `ITEMDELIVERY`. To be able to benefit from the partitioning and to be able to be partitioned itself, this table has a column `PARTITION_DATE`. `ITEMDELIVERY_ID` and `PARTITION_DATE` form the FK to `ITEMDELIVERY`.

`PARTITION_DATE` has no business meaning in `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` and is there only for technical reasons. Because of this, I would like to avoid specifying this column in my entity.
I tried the following in an implementation of `IAutoMappingOverride<ItemDeliveryDetail>`:

```
mapping.Map(x => x.ItemDelivery.DeliveryDate).Column("PARTITION_DATE");
```

But this didn't work, I get the following exception:

> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 'DeliveryDate' in class 'Domain.ItemDeliveryDetail'

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Looks like you need a query-only property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027032/query-only-properties-with-fluent-nhibernate. The answer is not accepted, so I'm not sure if this works with Fluent Nhibernate.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this is what I am after. To insert a new row into the table `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` the column `PARTITION_DATE` must not be `NULL`. If I understand the concept of query-only properties correctly, then this is not possible.

Comment: Ahh yes, of course! Then you have to resort to the [`access="private"` version of FluentNhibernate](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties).

Comment: @GertArnold: This sounds good. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the answer to this question is using a Reference to `ItemDelivery` in `ItemDeliveryDetail` you showed in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8477759/671619).

```
mapping.References(x => x.ItemDelivery)
    .Columns("ITEMDELIVERY_ID", "PARTITIONDATE");
```

this makes it invisible, automaticly filled and the Reference to its parent is sane

Comment: At first glance, this sounds even better.

Comment: "this makes it invisible, automaticly filled and the Reference to its parent is sane" --> If that's really the case, it would be perfect. I will check it as soon as the other question is resolved

Comment: Removing the explicit property and mapping does not only work but it is needed to make it work. It also was the solution to my other question linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In "classic" NHibernate I once solved a similar issue by adding `access="private"` to a property mapping. This tells NHibernate to map to a private member variable which, thus, is invisible to rest of the model.

Fluent NHibernate has a [solution](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties) for this that in their own words is not ideal, but it does support the feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in have it in your domain, why are you mapping it? If you want to map the property of the Item, then add it to the ItemDelivery class mapping

Comment: I don't follow. I need to map that column somehow, otherwise I am unable to insert new objects into the table, because part of the PK is empty