# Map table with composite key / foreign key to that table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to map a table that has a composite key and map another table that references this table.

Assume these tables:

1. `ITEMDELIVERY` with relevant columns:

   1. `ITEMDELIVERY_ID`
   2. `DELIVERY_DATE`
2. `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` with relevant columns:

   1. `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID`
   2. `ITEMDELIVERY_ID`
   3. `PARTITIONDATE`

The columns `ITEMDELIVERY.ITEMDELIVERY_ID` and `ITEMDELIVERY.DELIVERY_DATE` together form the PK.
The columns `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL.ITEMDELIVERY_ID` and `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL.PARTITIONDATE` form the FK from `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` to `ITEMDELIVERY`.

How do I map this?

I tried the following:

`IAutoMappingOverride<ItemDeliveryDetail>`:

```
mapping.References(x => x.ItemDelivery)
       .Columns("ITEMDELIVERY_ID", "PARTITIONDATE");
```

`IAutoMappingOverride<ItemDelivery>`:

```
mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ITEMDELIVERY_ID")
                     .KeyProperty(x => x.DeliveryDate, "DELIVERY_DATE");
```

But this doesn't work, it results in a `System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Double'.` when calling `SaveOrUpdate` on the session.

**UPDATE:**

I just checked the generated SQL and it shows that NHibernate somehow switches the values:

```
INSERT INTO ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL
       (ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID,      AMOUNT, PROCESSED_BY_REM, SINGLE_ITEM_PRICE, 
        ITEMDELIVERY_ID, PARTITIONDATE, SupplierInvoice_id)
VALUES (hibernate_sequence.nextval, :p0,    :p1,              :p2,               
        :p3,             :p4,           :p5)
returning ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID into :nhIdOutParam;

:p0 = 20.12.2011 16:29:44 [Type: Double (0)], 
:p1 = 6 [Type: DateTime (0)], 
:p2 = 21.12.2011 16:29:44 [Type: Double (0)], 
:p3 = 7 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
:p4 = 0 [Type: DateTime (0)], 
:p5 = 19.12.2011 16:29:44 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
:nhIdOutParam = 27638398 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

As you can see, the parameters are a complete mess...
They should be like this:

```
:p0 = 6 [Type: Double (0)], 
:p1 = 21.12.2011 16:29:44 [Type: DateTime (0)], 
:p2 = 7 [Type: Double (0)], 
:p3 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
:p4 = 19.12.2011 16:29:44 [Type: DateTime (0)], 
:p5 = 27638398 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
:nhIdOutParam = NULL [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Comment: looks like propertytype mismatch. What is the type of DeliveryDate in code and db?

Comment: @Firo: I hoped you would attend to my question :) About your comment: That's the strange thing: It's a `DateTime` in the code and in the database it's a `DATE`. But I am wondering: How does NHibernate know, how to map the columns? In my reference, I specify the two column names in the `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` table, but I do not specify the corresponding tables in `ITEMDELIVERY`...

Comment: the columns must have the same *order* as the CompositeId definition: ITEMDELIVERY_ID -> (column)ItemDelivery.Id | PARTITIONDATE -> (column)ItemDelivery.DeliveryDate. i wonder where the double comes from, do you have any other column or property which is a double? Maybe mapped with same columnname

Comment: @Firo: Please see update. Do you have any idea how this could happen? Or how I can trouble shoot it?

Comment: gratz. Dont forget to accept the answer as soon as you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The reason for this strange behavior was that I had an explicit property `PartitionDate`  that also was mapped (`mapping.Map(x => x.PartitionDate).Column("PARTITIONDATE");`).
This basically meant that the `PARTITIONDATE` column was mapped twice.