# Map composite key with unmapped column

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How do I map a composite key, if part of it is not mapped in my entity?

Example:

I have a table `ITEMDELIVERY` containing the columns:

- `ITEMDELIVERY_ID` (PK)
- `DELIVERY_DATE` (PK)

I have a table `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` containing the columns:

- `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID` (PK)
- `ITEMDELIVERY_ID` (FK)
- `PARTITIONDATE` (PK, FK)

As you can see, there is a composite key in both tables and `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` has a "composite" foreign key to `ITEMDELIVERY`.

There exists no property PartitionDate in my domain model `ItemDeliveryDetail` that could be mapped to the column `PARTITIONDATE` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492088/572644) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475685/map-partitioned-table-with-partition-discriminator-column) for the reasons).

But now, how do I map the composite key in `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL`?

I tried the following, but that doesn't work:

```
mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID")
                     .KeyProperty(x => x.ItemDelivery.DeliveryDate,
                                       "PARTITIONDATE");
```

I get the following error:

> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 'DeliveryDate' in class 'REM.Domain.NHibernate.ItemDeliveryDetail'

---

**UPDATE:**

I think I found the solution:

1. Remove the reference to `ItemDelivery` from the mapping of `ItemDeliveryDetail`: `mapping.References(x => x.ItemDelivery);.Columns("ITEMDELIVERY_ID", "PARTITIONDATE");`
2. Change the declaration of the composite key to this:

   ```
   mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID")
                        .KeyReference(x => x.ItemDelivery, "ITEMDELIVERY_ID",
                                                           "PARTITIONDATE");
   ```

This has the side effect that saving an `ItemDeliveryDetail` can't cascade save an `ItemDelivery`. It needs to be saved upfront.

However, I wonder about one thing:
**Will this create a PK with three columns? If so, how to avoid it and only create a PK for the two columns needed?**

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have a legacy db and will never generate it with SchemaExport, so it doesnt matter if NH thinks it has 3 PK columns or 1.

after looking at your question [Composite key with sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8493128/671619) and if your Id is unique alone then it would be better to

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SequenceIdentity("SQ_TRANSFORM_ITEMDEL_IDDID");
mapping.Reference(x => x.ItemDelivery).Columns("ITEMDELIVERY_ID", "PARTITIONDATE");
```

even if in the db the PK spans both columns

Update: tricky thing in your example of Invoice. There is a hack to have the second column in the join (as a where which the query optimizer should add to the join)

```
HasManyToMany(u => u.ItemDeliveryDetails)
    .Table("INVOICEITEM_IDD")
    .ChildWhere("PARTITIONDATE = nhGeneratedAliasForINVOICEITEM_IDD.PARTITIONDATE");
```

Comment: Your assumption about the legacy database is correct. However, the test database that will be used for persistence specification tests should be created by a schema export to ensure a clean and reliable test environment.

Comment: i have the same scenario, a legacy db and unit tests for the mappings. However i dont use SchemaExport because it may mask mapping errors. I exported the schema of the production database into a sqlscript which i execute just after creating the sessionfactory.

Comment: Good point. Still, there is another reason why I need to have the correct mappings: There are tables that have a foreign key to `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL`. To ensure that the generated joins are as fast as possible, this foreign key also needs to use both columns. If I use your answer, this won't work, because `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` is mapped with only a single ID...

Comment: Are you sure that performance degrades that much in oracle if only one column of the index (pk) is joined? I can't think of a way to simulate the db schema in the mappings without a lot of trouble

Comment: Yes. That was the whole purpose of introducing that column and the partitions when we created that database. It's a rather big table with 30 million entries... Just some numbers: A join without the partition date for a single row takes 11 seconds. A join with the partition date is instantaneous.

Comment: Can you post the other entity which references ItemDeliveryDetail? Maybe i can find a simple solution for it. Otherwise it will get nasty/hard work trying to map it like in db.

Comment: One example would be a simple mapping table `INVOICEITEM_IDD` with the columns `INVOICEITEM_ID`, `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID` and `PARTITIONDATE` with the last two columns being the FK to `ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL` This way, I would have a `HasManyToMany` relationshop in my `InvoiceItem` entity and that relationship would need to use the two columns.

Comment: I just now tried again to solve this problem and realized that you updated your answer back in December. I am sorry, I missed that! Is there a similar hack if I am just referencing the table (as in `mapping.References`)? Maybe with `Formula`?