# Composite key with sequence

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a composite key in my table and part of it needs to be generated by a sequence.
I tried the following, but it doesn't work - the line that sets the sequence name seems to be overridden by the composite key declaration that follows:

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SequenceIdentity("SQ_TRANSFORM_ITEMDEL_IDDID");
mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID")
                     .KeyReference(x => x.ItemDelivery, "ITEMDELIVERY_ID",
                                                        "PARTITIONDATE");
```

How to solve that problem?

Comment: is the sequence a default value or do you have to select the sequence value first? And is the Id alone not unique?

Comment: What do you mean with "default value" in the context of a sequence? The ID alone is unique because it is generated by a sequence. The partition date is part of the key because of table partitioning...

Answer (score 0):

Don't map ItemDelivery in a CompositeId but as a Reference see answer in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501524/671619). It's much easier overall.

Comment: This doesn't work, because other tables referencing `ItemDeliveryDetail` could then only use the ID for the reference. However, for speed reasons the `PARTITIONDATE` is also needed.